# Confusion regarding third parameter of numpy.random.binomial()

Tags: python, numpy

Should I do `numpy.random.binomial(100,0.5,1)` or `numpy.random.binomial(1,0.5,100)` and then sum?

Comment: I would expect the first to be more economical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both should be valid, but the first one is the most logical and efficient way to do it. The 3rd parameter (`size`) role is mainly to repeat the measure of `binomial(n,p)` if you want to get statistics on the validity of your result (e.g. if you obtain `binomial(100,0.5) = 45`, how likely was it to have this result (45)..). Note that in the case of the binomial function, the distribution can be directly accessed with [scipy.stats.binom](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binom.html#scipy.stats.binom)